# Is it possible to combine parameters in strapi to a search (_q)

Tags: mongodb, strapi

So if I have a query such as `localhost:1337/items/thing=abc&_q=all` It only runs `_q=all`.  Is there a **right** way to supply the parameters so that `thing=abc` is also queried?

Comment: So I did notice that you can delimit the _q query with abc|def.

Comment: This feature doesn't exist on Strapi now. You what to search OR you have to filter.